# Emacs file-local variables issue

Tags: emacs

Using Emacs 25.0.50.2, I seem to have having issues with file-local variables such as:

```
%%% Local Variables:
%%% coding: utf-8
%%% eval: (visual-line-mode 1)
%%% eval: (auto-fill-mode -1)
%%% End:
```

They seem to have no effect. If I change the case of the pseudo-variables to "Coding" and "Eval" (initial caps), then I am prompted as I should be for the variables but they still don't reliably set, auto-fill still being enabled. Did something change in emacs 25?

Comment: Don't raise bug reports for pre-release versions of Emacs in Stack Overflow? If it looks like a bug and it's not covered in the NEWS file, then `M-x report-emacs-bug`

Comment: Good point, I'd forgotten this was pre-release ...